# 'id' in where clause is ambiguous

Tags: grocery-crud

I have a table with some fields and some relations with others.

I get the list view with no problem, but when I try to filter the results (using the search feature in flexigrid table) I get:

> > ## A Database Error Occurred
> >
> > Error Number:
> >     1052
> >
> > Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous
> >
> > SELECT
> >     `gee_job_boards`.*, j32e2cb0f.dp_name AS s32e2cb0f FROM
> >     `gee_job_boards` LEFT JOIN `gee_distribution_partner` as `j32e2cb0f`
> >     ON `j32e2cb0f`.`id` = `gee_job_boards`.`dp_id` WHERE `id` LIKE '%27%'
> >     ESCAPE '!'  LIMIT 25
> >
> > Filename:
> >     models/Grocery_crud_model.php
> >
> > Line Number: 87
>
> Error Number: 1052
>
> Column 'id' in where clause is
>   ambiguous

how could i solve this ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should qualify your id in where clause, for example like this

```
j32e2cb0f.id LIKE ...
```

Comment: in which file we have to do changes

Comment: To elaborate on this since the table ID is probably dynamic.  You shouldn't normally overwrite $_POST data but just in case someone out there is stuck on an old version of grocery crud and having the same issue - found this to be the simplest solution:



$_POST['search_field'][0] = 'table_name.id';    (You will off course need to check what position the column appears in the search field array)